# Calling StartActivityResult inside adapter class and updating the recyclerview

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have an adapter class and calling **`startActivityForResult()`** and getting the result in my Activity where I am using the adapter.

I want to change the image view background on getting the result.And the change should effect only the particular position of the **`RecyclerView`**.

Answer (score 0):

`startActivityForResult()` inside the adapter class:
pass the context to your adapter class and do this:

```
((Activity)context).startActivityForResult(...);
```

As far as updating the `RecyclerView`, you can get the position inside the `onBindViewHolder()` and just update the class object from the `List` or `ArrayList`for the image and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after that.

P.S. this is the best I can do to explain to you without any code.

**Edit** : to get the `TextView` from the adapter class inside the Activity class:

```
View viewItem = recycleView.getLayoutManager().findViewByPosition(position);
TextView textView = viewItem.findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourColor));
```

Comment: I want to change the text view color from activity class is it possible?.The text view is declared in the RecyclerView's adapter class